# How scrollTop: is working in this jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

$(function() {
I have following code to work with. I am new in Jquery animate. I want to know how the scrollTop function is working here. Because in the official documentation there is no colon sign in front of scrollTop. This thing is confusing me. Thank You

```
$('a').bind('click', function (event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

    event.preventDefault(););
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fr2sy8ov/)

You need jQuery and jQuery UI for this to work with easing...Your code works fine in my example using `onDomReady` with an `<a href='#your-element-id'>`

**JS**

```
// this binds any and all <a> elements onclick to this event
$('a').bind('click', function (event) {
    // this was moved to the top as to stop event default action
    event.preventDefault();
    // grabbing the <a> that was clicked and getting it's element
    var $anchor = $(this);

    // This first stops any and all animations that might be happening with .stop
    // then it kicks off an animation
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        // scrollTop is the animation, we are grabbing the href value which should be declared as a selector with 1 result, then we are getting it's offset from the top (this will scroll up to that point [number of pixels from top])
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    // we want this animation to last for 1.5 seconds and we are using
    // easeInOutExpo which from https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html shows will start slowly get to max speed then slow down at the end of the animation again 
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But can you tell me how the function is working by elaborating its components.

Comment: @Saqib added comments, let me know if you need more

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed comments. I am newbie in Javascript and jquery. I really want to learn jquery and implement it. I want to become professional in front end web development. I really have passion for it.

Comment: @Saqib never a problem, hope it helps.  I highly recommend Pluralsight